What to do with repository exception in OpenRewrite?
What is wrong with the OpenRewrite plugin?

[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository https://central.maven.org/maven2

with root cause 'java.net.UnknownHostException: central.maven.org'


[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots

with root cause 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'



I assume that it is SSL related. Maybe I have some wrongly configured repositories?
Things that might affect this:

I have a custom settings.xml
Normally I work behind company VPN. This time it's switched off.
some dependencies have their origin in company repository

But the errors are not about that.
$ ./mvnw rewrite:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------< xxxx >---------------
[INFO] Building xxxxxx 1.3.2-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> rewrite-maven-plugin:5.32.1:run (default-cli) > process-test-classes @ xxxxxx >>>
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx downloading from company repo xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.7:prepare-agent (default-prepare-agent) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:/home/xxxxxx/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.7/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.7-runtime.jar=destfile=/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.18:build-info (default) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 19 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 42 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< rewrite-maven-plugin:5.32.1:run (default-cli) < process-test-classes @ xxxxxx <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- rewrite-maven-plugin:5.32.1:run (default-cli) @ xxxxxx ---
[INFO] Using active recipe(s) [org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.SpringBootProperties_3_1]
[INFO] Using active styles(s) []
[INFO] Validating active recipes...
[INFO] Project [xxxxxx] Resolving Poms...
[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository https://central.maven.org/maven2
java.net.UnknownHostException: central.maven.org
    at sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect (NioSocketImpl.java:567)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Socket.java:751)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect (SSLSocketImpl.java:304)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect (NetworkClient.java:178)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer (HttpClient.java:636)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init> (HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New (HttpsClient.java:377)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:193)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1237)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect (HttpURLConnection.java:1123)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:179)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)
    at org.openrewrite.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send (HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:97)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.lambda$sendRequest$1 (MavenPomDownloader.java:149)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$toCtxSupplier$11 (Functions.java:243)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0 (Functions.java:46)
    at dev.failsafe.internal.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$apply$0 (RetryPolicyExecutor.java:74)
    at dev.failsafe.SyncExecutionImpl.executeSync (SyncExecutionImpl.java:187)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call (FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get (FailsafeExecutor.java:112)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.sendRequest (MavenPomDownloader.java:148)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.normalizeRepository (MavenPomDownloader.java:755)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.distinctNormalizedRepositories (MavenPomDownloader.java:677)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:514)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPom (ResolvedPom.java:498)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentDependenciesRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:433)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:381)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:890)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:806)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:174)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:116)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:59)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:557)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.listSourceFiles (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:149)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.loadSourceSet (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:135)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:117)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[WARNING] Failed to access maven repository https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException (Alert.java:130)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:378)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:321)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal (TransportContext.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:647)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:467)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:393)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:476)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:447)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:201)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:172)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:586)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)
    at org.openrewrite.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send (HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:97)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.lambda$sendRequest$1 (MavenPomDownloader.java:149)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$toCtxSupplier$11 (Functions.java:243)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0 (Functions.java:46)
    at dev.failsafe.internal.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$apply$0 (RetryPolicyExecutor.java:74)
    at dev.failsafe.SyncExecutionImpl.executeSync (SyncExecutionImpl.java:187)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call (FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get (FailsafeExecutor.java:112)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.sendRequest (MavenPomDownloader.java:148)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.normalizeRepository (MavenPomDownloader.java:755)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.distinctNormalizedRepositories (MavenPomDownloader.java:677)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:514)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPom (ResolvedPom.java:498)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentDependenciesRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:433)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:381)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:890)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:806)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:174)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:116)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:59)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:557)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.listSourceFiles (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:149)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.loadSourceSet (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:135)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:117)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild (PKIXValidator.java:388)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate (PKIXValidator.java:242)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate (Validator.java:256)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:631)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:467)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:393)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:476)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:447)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:201)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:172)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:586)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)
    at org.openrewrite.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send (HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:97)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.lambda$sendRequest$1 (MavenPomDownloader.java:149)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$toCtxSupplier$11 (Functions.java:243)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0 (Functions.java:46)
    at dev.failsafe.internal.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$apply$0 (RetryPolicyExecutor.java:74)
    at dev.failsafe.SyncExecutionImpl.executeSync (SyncExecutionImpl.java:187)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call (FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get (FailsafeExecutor.java:112)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.sendRequest (MavenPomDownloader.java:148)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.normalizeRepository (MavenPomDownloader.java:755)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.distinctNormalizedRepositories (MavenPomDownloader.java:677)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:514)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPom (ResolvedPom.java:498)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentDependenciesRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:433)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:381)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:890)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:806)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:174)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:116)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:59)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:557)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.listSourceFiles (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:149)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.loadSourceSet (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:135)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:117)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build (SunCertPathBuilder.java:148)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild (SunCertPathBuilder.java:129)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build (CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild (PKIXValidator.java:383)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate (PKIXValidator.java:242)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate (Validator.java:256)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts (CertificateMessage.java:631)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate (CertificateMessage.java:467)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume (CertificateMessage.java:363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume (SSLHandshake.java:393)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:476)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch (HandshakeContext.java:447)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch (TransportContext.java:201)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode (SSLTransport.java:172)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode (SSLSocketImpl.java:1506)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord (SSLSocketImpl.java:1421)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake (SSLSocketImpl.java:426)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect (HttpsClient.java:586)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect (AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:187)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0 (HttpURLConnection.java:1675)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream (HttpURLConnection.java:1599)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnection.java:531)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:307)
    at org.openrewrite.ipc.http.HttpUrlConnectionSender.send (HttpUrlConnectionSender.java:97)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.lambda$sendRequest$1 (MavenPomDownloader.java:149)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$toCtxSupplier$11 (Functions.java:243)
    at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0 (Functions.java:46)
    at dev.failsafe.internal.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$apply$0 (RetryPolicyExecutor.java:74)
    at dev.failsafe.SyncExecutionImpl.executeSync (SyncExecutionImpl.java:187)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call (FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
    at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.get (FailsafeExecutor.java:112)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.sendRequest (MavenPomDownloader.java:148)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.normalizeRepository (MavenPomDownloader.java:755)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.distinctNormalizedRepositories (MavenPomDownloader.java:677)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.internal.MavenPomDownloader.download (MavenPomDownloader.java:514)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentPom (ResolvedPom.java:498)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentDependenciesRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:433)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom$Resolver.resolveParentsRecursively (ResolvedPom.java:381)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:890)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.ResolvedPom.resolveDependencies (ResolvedPom.java:806)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.tree.MavenResolutionResult.resolveDependencies (MavenResolutionResult.java:174)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenParser.parseInputs (MavenParser.java:116)
    at org.openrewrite.Parser.parse (Parser.java:59)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.parseMaven (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:557)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.MavenMojoProjectParser.listSourceFiles (MavenMojoProjectParser.java:149)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.loadSourceSet (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:135)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.listResults (AbstractRewriteBaseRunMojo.java:117)
    at org.openrewrite.maven.AbstractRewriteRunMojo.execute (AbstractRewriteRunMojo.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[INFO] Project [xxxxxx] Parsing source files
[WARNING] There were problems parsing some source files, run with --errors to see full stack traces
[WARNING] There were problems parsing src/main/resources/public/docs/xxxxxx.yaml
[WARNING] There were problems parsing src/main/docker/xxxx-dev.yml
[INFO] Running recipe(s)...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  20.635 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-06-11T13:01:52+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------




We've had a few similar reports before; https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/4101
The question mostly is: does this block you from achieving any recipe changes?

Since the SpringBootProperties_3_1 recipe you're running is unlikely to produce much, but UpgradeSpringBoot_3_1 might produce more results.

Tim, you were right: the properties recipe didn't do anything so I assumed it was blocking. The upgrade spring boot recipe however works. So all stack-traces (and those are a lot!!!) are non blocking.
BTW in the meantime I installed mvn 3.9.8. For others, trying to reproduce: it might had an effect, but I think changing the recipe here was the main misunderstanding of me.

UnknownHostException usually refers to DNS problems.
Check your network connectivity and DNS settings. Pay particular attention to IPv4 vs. IPv6 settings.
To verify that DNS is working correctly, run something like ping central.maven.org on the host where Maven is running. (You can use -4 or -6 switch to test separately IPv4 and IPv6).

$ ping central.maven.org --> ping: central.maven.org: Name or service not known

I can ping others domains though..

I also can't resolve that name. This would mean that Maven (or one of its plugins) is using the wrong hostname, my first thought would be to update Maven (and all its plugins/dependencies) to their latest versions.

I thought you meant updating the dependencies themselves, but now I understand that you suggest to update maven (binaries) itself. I'll try, thanks.

I upgraded to 3.9.8 but the error kept coming. Like Tim above suggested it was a coincidence of the wrong recipe (my mistake) that gave no effects in terms of code changes and openrewrites alarming logging which is unimportant for following the recipe.
